# How to force portrait orientation if device is in landscape orientation when the app launches in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, ios8, screen-orientation

My application allows all four orientations, but the rootviewcontroller should only allow portrait orientation.

I override the supportedInterfaceOrientations method in my rootviewcontroller, but if the device is held in landscape orientation when the app launches then the view controller displayed incorrectly in landscape orientation even though only portrait orientation is allowed.  This is an iOS 8 specific issue.

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In ViewController:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Swift version:

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
    return true
}
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int {
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
}
```

Comment: I need to select all orientations because a couple view controllers require landscape orientation.

Comment: @MobileDev98 I'm thinking you are using `supportedInterfaceOrientaions` wrong. You should use `UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait` instead of `UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait`. Check out my new edit.

Comment: override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> Int{
        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)|Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.PortraitUpsideDown.rawValue)
    }

Comment: override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

Comment: supportedInterfaceOrientations method is getting called but not shouldAutorotate

Comment: @MobileDev98 Won't `application.statusBarOrientation` affect all view controllers?

Answer (score 0):

For me implementing AppDelegate function application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow did the trick

```
func application(application: UIApplication, supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow) -> Int {

    if let viewController = self.window?.rootViewController?.presentedViewController as? PortraitViewController{

        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
    }else{

        return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue)
    }

}
```

where PortraitViewController should be replaced with the name of your root view controller class